# How to register DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll for my COM dll project

Tags: c#, dll, com, gac, regasm

I have a small problem with using assembly in my project.
I have to make COM dll, to use in other application, that used OpenXML SDK for faster load xlsx files. And it work perfectly on my machine. But there is problems, then I tried to port my project to another machine. 
For COM dll I create reg file by by "regasm" with registration my COM DLL classes in registry. Without reference to OpenXML dll it works perfectly, but with reference to OpenXML dll it causes 80040154 error.
I make little program with dll's and reg file in resources, to register on new machine my COM dll. 
In manifest.app added:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

As I said without OpenXML dll - COM dll works.
At first I think, that I should register on new machine DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll in GAC. I tried to do it with Publish.Gacinstall(), but there is no result.

```
namespace Reger_XLSReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string dir = @"c:\windows\system32\";
            File.WriteAllBytes(dir + "XLSReader.dll", Properties.Resources.XLSReader);
            File.WriteAllText("xls.reg", Properties.Resources.xls);
            File.WriteAllBytes(dir  + "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll", Properties.Resources.DocumentFormat_OpenXml);
            Publish pub = new Publish();
            pub.GacInstall(dir  + "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll");
            Process.Start("xls.reg");
        }
    }
}
```

After I tried to install OpenXML SDK manually on new machine and check for GAC registration for DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll - it's registered, but I have error anyway. 80040154 - class not registered.
I don't understand, what VS2015 do with my DLL and DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll for normal working and how to do it on machine without VS.
In my experiments, I made windows form application with using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll, and port it to other machine. Works perfectly without any registration in GAC and installation OpenXML SDK on machine. All it need - DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll in the same with exe directory.

So the question is - what should I do, to use my COM dll with reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll on any machine?

Sorry for wrong English.